# Creating asp:Table from c# backend in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

For some reason my code isn't being displayed like a normal table it is just outputting a block of text instead.

**Here is the code I have written in the backend to create my table:**

```
    protected void LoadData(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //Populating a DataTable from database.
        DataTable dt = this.GetData();

        //Building an HTML string.
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

        //Table start.
        html.Append("<asp:Table ID=\"Table2\" runat=\"Server\" CellPadding=\"2\" CellSpacing=\"1\" BorderColor = \"CadetBlue\" BorderWidth = \"1\" BorderStyle = \"Dashed\" >");

        //Building the Data rows.
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<asp:TableRow runat=\"Server\" BorderWidth=\"1\">");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<asp:TableCell runat=\"Server\" BorderWidth=\"1\">");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</asp:TableCell>");
            }
            html.Append("</asp:TableRow>");
        }

        //Table end.
        html.Append("</asp:Table>");

        //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
    }
```

**This is a sample of the output im getting:**

> Yamaha XTZ 650) N/Yamaha TRXBentley H-SectionBentley I-SectionBMW SPFord 5.23 NarrowFord 6.173 NarrowSuzuki GSX-R 750Non-Split I-SectionNissan GTR6Peugeot 1.9Vauxhall CorsaFerrariBMW SPFord SPTR3 SPTR6 SPSteyr PuchClimax WLKHealey 3000Vauxhall SPRS2000Peugeot/BMWPeugeot 5/16MGB 1800Peugeot 3/8F3 Ext. 5/16BLSFord CVH 1600F3 5/16F3 5/16Ford Zetec Bushed S/EFord 5.65 NarrowPeugeot SPFord Zetec SPVolvo SPVolvo SPBMW SPPeugeotFord 5.4 SPOpel 2.3 DAlfa Romeo V6LagondaVauxhall Ext.Ford 5.4 NarrowFord 5.0 NarrowFord 4.926 WideHonda CRXPeugeot 5/16 SPMini Cooper Ext.Lagonda Ext.Audi 5CylPeugeot SPF3Unknown V6Mountune SpecialTriumph SPVauxhall Corsa Ext.Ford Cosworth SierraF3Ford Narrow SPRS2000 SPCosworth

**I just want it to come out in a table structure**'

Comment: Just follow this example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/showing-table-data-in-dynamically-created-table-in-Asp-Net-c/  i.e. don't use an asp table control, just use a plain html table.

Comment: `<asp:TableRow` is not really HTML. That's server side markup that gets rendered to HTML later on. You need to programmatically create instances of the controls rather than doing it via string. Alternatively, use real HTML markup such as `table` element instead of `asp:Table` control.

Comment: @RickS If i was to use a html table would i be able to add functionality to the cells?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example for you : (https://forums.asp.net/t/1797172.aspx?How+to+create+table+dynamically+in+asp+net)

First put a asp:Literal control in you page where you want to show your table, as below

```
    <asp:Literal ID="litTable" runat="server" />
```

Now in your the event where data is fetched, write the below code to loop though data source and build a table

```
    StringBuilder htmlTable = new StringBuilder();
    htmlTable .AppendLine("<table">");
    htmlTableString.AppendLine("<tr>");
    htmlTableString.AppendLine("<th>colum 1</th>");
    htmlTableString.AppendLine("<th>colum 2</th>");
    htmlTableString.AppendLine("<th>colum 3</th>");
    htmlTableString.AppendLine("</tr>");
```

/*Put a for loop here and repeat the below code*/

```
    htmlTableString.AppendLine("<tr>");
    htmlTableString.AppendLine("<td>colum 1 data</td>");
    htmlTableString.AppendLine("<td>colum 2 data</td>");
    htmlTableString.AppendLine("<td>colum 3 data</td>");
    htmlTableString.AppendLine("</tr>");
```

/*End For loop*/

```
    htmlTableString.AppendLine("</table>");
    litTable.Text = htmlTableString.ToString();
```

This will create an HTML string and assign to you literal, thats all!